# Invalid usage of the option flush_interval_seconds in the ALTER DATABASE statement

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, sql-query-store

I have created a database project in visual studio, but when I publish I get the error:

> Invalid usage of the option flush_interval_seconds in the ALTER DATABASE statement

And the code that is generated is:

> Msg 153, Level 15, State 5, Line 5
>   Invalid usage of the option flush_interval_seconds in the ALTER DATABASE statement.
>   (43,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET QUERY_STORE (DATA_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 0, INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES = 0) 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END
```

> SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 153, Level 16, State 6, Line 5
>   Invalid usage of the option interval_length_minutes in the ALTER DATABASE statement.
>
> (43,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET QUERY_STORE (DATA_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 0, INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES = 0) 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END
```

> An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

I am struggling to find any reference on this, and what causes it, and ultimately how to fix it, so any guidance is appreciated.

**Edit**: the above SQL is auto generated when the DB is published from Visual Studio

Comment: That SQL, have you written that or is that generated by Visual Studio?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, that is auto generated SQL when the DB is published from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set it up using Visual Studio.

Solution Explorer-> Database Project -> Right Click -> Properties -> Project Settings -> Database Settings -> Query Store

Change 0 to desired value.

---

Related: [SSDT: SQL Project Options](http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssdt-sql-project-options.html) and [Database Project Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/database-project-settings?view=sql-server-2017#bkmk_proj_settings)

If this does not work, it means that you have custom SQL Script in Pre/Post Deployment folder.

Comment: Thank you, those settings are what I was needing but could not find.

Comment: @Leonidas199x Yes, they are "hidden". Other option is edditing XML version of db project direction but I do not recommend doing it :)

Answer (score 2):

A zero value for `DATA_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS` doesn't make sense as the value is for the asynchronous flush. I think 60 seconds is the minimum. Also, 1 minute is the minimum for `INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES`, the size of the fixed-length statistics time window.

Comment: Thanks - I should have added, this code is auto generated by visual studio, I have not written it.